# How to fix automatic login in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-users

How to fix automatic login in Django?

When Someone goes to someone profile by typing URL like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/1` so when the page loaded it will automatic login to person profile, for example, the admin had 1 profile with `pk=1` so if some type URL like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/1` he will log in to admin without password username

I Want Like This No Body Can log in To Profile with a link and He Can Only View Someone Profile Not Login To Someone Profile

Here is my **Views.py**

```
def profile_detail(request,pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    model = user_register_model()
    return render(request,'profile_detail_view.html',{'user':user,'model':model,})

#register  view


def user_reg(request):
    register = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = user_register_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            register = True

            if register == True:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/login")

        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = user_register_form()

    context = {'reg':form,}
    return render(request,'signup.html',context)
```

Here is my **Base.html**

```
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <li class="nav-item">

    <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'profile' pk=user.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">

    <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'logout' %}"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>
  </li>

  {% else %}
  <li class="nav-item">

    <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'register' %}"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>&nbsp; Sign up Free</a>
  </li>    
  <li class="nav-item">

    <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'login' %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Login</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
```

Here is my **Profile_Detail_View.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-5">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Full Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-6">
        {{user.username}}
    </div>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-5">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Join Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-6">
        {{ model.join_date|date:"M d,Y" }}
    </div>
</div>
<hr />


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-5">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-6">
        {{ user.email }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my **Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class user_register_model(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Here is my **Urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    path('accounts/signup/', views.user_reg,name='register'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>',views.profile_detail,name='profile')

]
```

Here is The **Gif Video**:

[image]

Comment: you can use if request.user.is_authenticated: clause in your views or use a login required decorator

Comment: But i don't want login required decorator because he don't allow to view profile i want something like this someone can view profile but not login to profile

Comment: Because When i type url it will automatically login to this profile

Comment: Without Password And Username i want something like that you can view his someone profile but not automatically login

Comment: i think you haven't implemented django user authentication and login system, go through the docs and implement it

Comment: I Read It And I work on some proejcts also but this this time i get this error

Comment: it's time to start using [CLASS BASED VIEWS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/)

Comment: i also know about Class Based Views

Comment: Wait I will upload a gif so you guys understand better

Comment: Please Check The Gif Question Updated

Comment: You say, for viewing the profile login is not required, but your navbar link is inside the authentication. Also try in reverse way, with if not user is authenticated

Comment: @HamzaLachi can you show your signup and login view

Comment: @arjun Sure Wait I will update my question

Comment: @arjun question updated i use django login view

Comment: @arjun i used django builtin view in urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i missed a request in **base.html**

i need to replace this line:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
```

To This:

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
```